# C++ error: "Using obsolete binding"

Tags: c++

My compiler isn't liking several things about the following code. Any help much appreciated. Feel free to criticize the hell out of me since I'm a programming n00b. I know you guys can be harsh.

```
// Method 2, the additive swap, explained inside. 
void strrev2(std::string& str) { 
    unsigned len = str.size(); 
    for (unsigned i = 0, j = len - 1; i < j; i++, j--) { 
        short a = (int)str[i]; // a is the ASCII value of the i-th character of the string
        short b = (int)str[j]; // b is the ASCII value of the j-th character of the string

        //             Current value of a        Current value of b
        a = a + b; //      a + b                         b        
        b = a - b; //      a + b                         a
        a = a - b; //        b                           a
    }

    str[i] = (char)a;
    str[j] = (char)b;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You should identify the compiler (and version) you're using.  You should also report exactly the error message you got, and identify the line numbers in the source code you show (so that we can see exactly which line each error is reported against).  Without that, it is more difficult to know what your problem is, though it looks like Adam Burry has identified the cause (but it would still be interesting to know which compiler).

Comment: Your last 2 assignments should be in your loop body.

Comment: Adam's got it. I'm curious what compiler you're using that uses "obsolete binding" as an error message. I've never seen that one.

Comment: I get the same error with llvm-g++-4.2. All four variables go out of scope, but are referenced after the loop.

Comment: That's a dreadful (and dreadfully complex) way of writing the swap code. `char a = str[i]; str[i] = str[j]; str[j] = a;` is so much simpler and saner.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, for that matter there's std::swap.

Comment: @AdamBurry: Given that it's C++, yup...there is...

Comment: "I know you guys can be harsh." Lol. It's funny cos it's true.

Answer (score 5):

`i,j,a,b` are not available outside of `for` loop, but you are trying to access them outside `for` loop. You could consider move `str[i] = (char)a;` inside the loop:

```
for (unsigned i = 0, j = len - 1; i < j; i++, j--) { 
  ....
  ...
  str[i] = (char)a;
  str[j] = (char)b;   
}
```

Comment: Whoops .... I'm an idiot.

Comment: @MarshallMathers: If that is your criteria for being an idiot, there are an appalling number of idiots out there. This situation is treated as a warning by some compilers, in particular ones written before the rules of scoping for loop control statements were well-defined. Or if using switches like `-fpermissive`. The _real_ idiots are the ones who ignore the warning, which is why it is a good thing modern compilers have promoted this to a full-blown error.

Comment: Real idiots like teachers in india who use turbo c++ and ignore the scoping rules.